# htaccess changed and looks strange

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have an wordpress site and today I saw a strange code in .htaccess. And I don't know if the hackers can attack my wordpress using the rules from htaccess.

Here is the code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+).*..*\/O.*O.*OTOT(.*).*-.*\/.*S(.*).*OTU.*-[0-9]+..*$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+).*..*\/(.*).*SO.*O.*O.*-.*\/.*S(.*).*OT.*S-[0-9]+..*$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+).*..*\/OT.*S.*SU.*-.*\/.*S(.*).*U.*OT-[0-9]+..*$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+).*..*\/.*S.*S.*-.*\/.*S(.*).*U.*OT-[0-9]+..*$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+).*..*\/(.*).*SO.*O.*O.*-.*\/.*S(.*).*U.*O.*-[0-9]+..*$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([^\d\/]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-NS(.*)\/([0-9]+)I(.*)-.*\/.*-.*-.*-.*[0-9]+..*$ ?$1$7=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+).*..*\/O.*OTO.*S-.*\/.*S(.*).*OTU.*-[0-9]+..*$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)(.*)%[0-9]+F%[0-9]+F.*..*%[0-9]+F.*-.*%[0-9]+F$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)..*\/O.*S(.*).*U.*(.*)H-.*\/.*S(.*).*OTOT-[0-9]+..*$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)..*\/(.*).*(.*)HO.*(.*).*(.*).*-.*\/.*S(.*).*OTOT-[0-9]+..*$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)(.*)%[0-9]+F%[0-9]+F.*..*%[0-9]+F.*%[0-9]+F.*-.*%[0-9]+F$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)..*$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)(.*)%[0-9]+F%[0-9]+F.*..*%[0-9]+F&#[0-9]+;.*=.*$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)(.*)%[0-9]+F%[0-9]+F.*..*%[0-9]+F$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)..*\/(.*).*(.*)HOTOTO.*-.*\/.*S(.*).*OTOT-[0-9]+..*$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)..*\/O.*S.*(.*).*-.*\/.*S(.*).*OTOT-[0-9]+..*$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([^\d\/]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-.*-.*-.*-.*$ ?$1$3=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)&.*P.*=[0-9]+$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/([^\d\/]+)\/([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)..*$ ?$2$4=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}([a-zA-Z0-9]{5,19})/([0-9]{1,7}).htm$ index.php?tempweb=$1&smid=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What version of wordpress?

Comment: 4.7.4 is the last

Answer (score 0):

Any Site speed optimizing Plugins?
W3 Total Cache? Wp-Rocket? iTheme Security etc?

I met kinda similar thing and those were generated by those plugins. Just erase and scan the site :)